# Ordering by datetime for nested objects using PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, activerecord, sql-order-by

I'd like to sort my board by the frequency of when post is created or updated. I've been able to do this but the **exact** ordering is still off. For instance, if I have 2 posts (A, B) and update B, that post still appears second to A. I've had this problem with PostgreSQL before and solved it using the object's `id` as a secondary sorting column. Unfortunately in this case I'm going by posts. Based on my code, what seems to be the problem?

```
class Board < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :board
end
```

---

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @active_boards = Board
      .includes(:posts)
      .where.not(posts: { board_id: nil })
      .order('posts.created_at ASC', 'posts.updated_at ASC')
      .limit(10)
  end
end
```

Comment: Why don't you just sort by updated_at as that gets set whether the record is being created or updated.

Comment: `order('posts.created_at ASC', 'posts.updated_at ASC')` means that if 2 posts share the exact same `created_at`, use `updated_at` to break the tie. The suggestion that @PaulByrne made will work since when a record is created, `created_at == updated_at`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first possibility is to also set `updated_at` when a post is inserted, then you can simply use that column.

The other option is to `ORDER BY max(created_at, updated_at)`.

Comment: "The first possibility is to also set updated_at when a post is inserted, then you can simply use that column." Isn't that what I'm doing now?

Comment: You don't show... a simple way would be to define the column as `updated_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT current_timestamp` and not insert anything into this column, so that the default value is used.